# Dart Socket.connect fails when phone is connected to ESP32 access point

Tags: android, flutter, dart, networking, esp32

```
var socket = await Socket.connect(ip, port);
```

I'm attempting to connect to a local device from my phone (Pixel 4a), using Dart/Flutter. This succeeds when both my phone and the other device are on my router's local network. When I connect them to an ESP32 access point however, this code awaits indefinitely. It doesn't matter what the target device is, I've tried several. I've had other devices connect successfully on the ESP32 access point, so I'm certain it's not the ESP32 firmware. Only my phone refuses to connect when on the ESP32 access point. Unfortunately, I don't have another phone to test, so I don't know if this is Android-specific or model-specific.

The ESP32 access point does not have internet access, but that shouldn't matter for this purpose, as I'm trying to connect local devices. I suspect that something in Dart/Android is refusing to route to the address, despite it being accessible.

What is a possible cause for this refusal to connect? Is there another networking API in the Dart/Flutter environment that could give me more information? Perhaps a lower-level one? Some sort of error code would be far better than indefinite awaiting. Would I need to link to a function in another language to get more details? Java/C?

Thank you.

Comment: does the device you trying to connect to have authentication ? if so use `Process` is in `dart:io` use for shell command like using `curl`

Comment: No, it's a plain server TCP server listening at a known port. I just need to exchange a few bytes then close.

Comment: I'm not expert on MCU (Arduino in general) but when i work with it, i believe that `Dart Socket` is not the same as `C Socket` i think this video will help you [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjxtwQ8Xpuo)

Comment: I discovered that my phone refuses to use non-internet-connected wifi if mobile data is on. Turning mobile data off allowed my phone to connect to the other device on the ESP32 access point.